# How to import Express js into React js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

Is it possible to import Express js into React js? I've used Express js for database connection with MySql which retrieves rows from a table. I need to display result in react app. How can that be achieved?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log('http://localhost:'+ PORT);
});

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database : 'example'
 });

 connection.query('SELECT * from customers', function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (!err)

     console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
   else
     console.log('Error while performing Query.');
 });

 connection.end();
```

Comment: you have to open api from you express app and call them from your react front end.

Comment: I don't think you understand correctly how these technologies are related...if you have an express.js server, then you need to send requests to it, which doesn't really have anything to do with react. Try reading about [asynchronous requests in React](http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in node

```
app.get('/customers', function (req, res) {
 connection.query('SELECT * from customers', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err)
    //process your db result here and then response
   res.json(result);
    connection.end();
 else
   res.status(500).json(err);
   connection.end();
 });


})
```

in react you can use fetch module

```
 fetch(`http://<host>:<port>/customers`) 
        .then(result=> {
            //here inside result you have the response from your express app
        });
```

Comment: Where are you suggesting putting those pieces of code, and how should the result be used within a react component?

Comment: This is really a broad question. People have there own way of doing things. Normally you should write middle ware in express to handle this kind of db query and separate them in a new file. In react component you make this call when some event happens. Look into this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oiXG9f6GO0&index=1&list=PLuNEz8XtB51K-x3bwCC9uNM_cxXaiCcRY . This guy used redux thunk middleware to dispatch action(make api call). Its a good video to start with react and express.

Comment: You're right, that's why I voted to close the question as broad, rather than trying to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your React app on your Express server by simply adding this route:

```
// React
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../dist/index.html'));
});
```

But of course you should provide your own path to the React "entry point".
After this you can simply reach the endpoint of your API using fetch in React component(or Redux's action/reducer or wherever you like)

With this solution you will not have to keep 2 separate server up (one for React app and another for your API)

Comment: how could this work with react native?

Comment: I never used react native, but I'd assume there is nothing to do with Express except an api your react native app will be consuming